Acceptance Rate vs Temperature in Simulated Annealing
In simulated annealing, how does the acceptance rate (percentage of sample points accepted at each generation of sample values) change with the temperature?

I don't know why the question gets downvoted. Many different formulas can be found in the literature, including not changing the acceptance rate at all

Picture this: Your acceptance rate is a trust gauge, each time you accept a solution that is worse than your current best solution, you decrease your trust/temperature. By extension, the acceptance rate is represented by the temperature.
